# Can someone explain me performance benefits related to destructuring according to this article

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2016

I'm a beginner and learning javaScript.I need help regarding destructuring and performance of destructuring rather than just assigning.I'm providing a link to this article.can anyone relate this with an example.

A part of this article says,

> There are two big advantages of using destructuring. The first one is that your code more readable. If you destructure an object at the top of a function or code block, it is clear to the reader what variables you are going to use.

> The second plus is performance. Destructuring encourages programmers to **put object properties in local variables before using them,which can improve application performance. Especially if you are accessing those variables multiple times, maybe in a loop, it is more efficiënt if the variables are locally defined** .

can someone help me understand this part. Thanks

[https://wecodetheweb.com/2015/05/25/es6-destructuring/#:~:text=There%20are%20two%20big%20advantages,The%20second%20plus%20is%20performance](https://wecodetheweb.com/2015/05/25/es6-destructuring/#:%7E:text=There%20are%20two%20big%20advantages,The%20second%20plus%20is%20performance)

Answer (score 2):

The "performance benefits" is simply that it encourages developers to assign data to variables. That way they don't keep accessing the object to get the value repeatedly. It would be the difference between this

```js
const data = { el: 10 }
const { el } = data
console.log(el)
console.log(el)
console.log(el)
```

and this

```js
const data = { el: 10 }
console.log(data.el)
console.log(data.el)
console.log(data.el)
```

In the first one, you have assigned the value to a variable. Your code will simply keep grabbing that reference. In the second code snippet, the reference is getting the *entire object* and then accessing its `el` key.

The performance difference is so trivial that I can't believe the author thought it was even worth mentioning. The performance difference of accessing data in either situation is so small (probably on the scale of nanoseconds), that it doesn't matter at all. Don't worry about that part of the article. It's pure nonsense

Comment: but what if object size is very large ?@Andrew

Comment: @samiksha-jagtap I don't see how that can make any difference: the "overhead", if any, is that you are accessing a "sub-index" of the contiguous memory referenced by `data` (which I believe is implemented pretty much like a C struct), _then_ accessing the value referenced by this field.. so you double the "dereferencing" operations. But also defining `el` via destructuring technically binds it to the local scope, which I believe is in its own regard still an object/struct, and is still tested/accessed similarly